# SqlConnection timeout oddities

Tags: c#, wpf, timeout, async-await, sqlconnection

I am experiencing a weird issue where the timeout remaining for a connection attempt seems to be persisting through multiple attempts.

I have a simple window where connection information is entered, with a connect and cancel button.

When the user hits connect, the following code executes:

```
 DisableControls();
 if((bool)AutoAuthenticated.IsChecked)
 {
     ((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                                          ("server="+ServerName.Text + ";"+
                                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;"  +
                                          "database="+DatabaseName.Text + ";" +
                                          "connection timeout=3");
 }
 else
 {
     ((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
     ("user id="+UserName.Text+";" +
     "password="+Password.Password+";" +
     "server="+ServerName.Text+";" +
     "Trusted_Connection=no;" +
     "database="+DatabaseName.Text+";" +
     "connection timeout=3");
 }

 await ConnectToServer();
```

This is the ConnectToServer function:

```
private async Task ConnectToServer()
{
    //using (((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection)
    //{ 
        await ((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection.OpenAsync();
    //}
}
```

The timeout property is small right now for the purposes of testing.

Anyway, if the user hits the cancel button whilst connecting:

```
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection != null &&
        ((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection.State ==
            System.Data.ConnectionState.Connecting)
    {
        ((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection.Close();
        EnableControls();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, if I enter in bogus details and leave it to timeout, then I catch the exception with 'The network path was not found.'.

If I try and connect again after this (or maybe the one after the next attempt depending on how quick I was to hit the cancel button), it times out almost instantly after hitting the connect button, without waiting the amount of time it was supposed to.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I've tried looking in to resetting the SqlConnection object, but I thought the setting of it to a new SqlConnection each time I hit connect should be doing this already?

Comment: This has nothing to do with async-await, right? If you call SqlConnection.Open() instead of SqlConnection.OpenAsyc the same thing happens, right?

Comment: Are you aware of how many strings you are creating with that connection string building code? Just using [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.String.Format.aspx) or a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Text.StringBuilder.aspx) would be a huge benefit, but, since you're specifically building a SQL connection string, a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.aspx)

Comment: I was using `OpenAsync()` so that the application didn't lock up whilst trying to connect.  I have just tested and the same thing DOES occur if I just use `Open()`.  Also, when you say 'are you aware of how many strings you are creating', I'm not sure how what you're saying will help.  The parameters passed in are subject to change, so I'd be rebuilding the string each time this function is called anyway, regardless of how I am doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was missing.  Even when closing the connection, disposing of the object, keeping it all in a using statement, the issue persisted because there was another element that I was unaware of - the connection pool.

I still have to do some reading on this, but basically it reuses old connection information and so on to save on resources, etc.

There's more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543.aspx), but in case this helps someone else with similar issues, just call the `ClearPool()` function when you close the connection:

Example (in my exception handling code, and after I call Close()):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearPool(((MainWindow)Owner).myConnection);
```

Obviously from a resource usage perspective, it would probably be best to call that function only when you don't need to reuse the connection, but that said, I still need to read up on this so don't take my word for it!

Comment: It seems like in a mult-threaded app (such as a web app) just calling .ClearPool() might reset any connections in the pool that are still active/in use in other threads. Perhaps it would be better to leave opening the connection as a synchronous operation, and placing your await at a higher level of abstraction. It's just taking the task in a larger chunk.

Comment: But I still want to do it in a way that doesn't obstruct the UI.  The user shouldn't be able to open more than one connection at once anyway as I disable the controls.  The await occurs in an event (the clicking of the Connect button) as it is, so I'm not sure how much higher up I can make that?  Also, how could I have other connections using the Sqlconnection object at the same time anyway?  I thought I could only use one Sqlconnection for one...sql connection, and that if I wanted more than one connection at once, I would need more than one Sqlconnection object.

Comment: And my call to `ClearPool()` should only affect the SqlConnection object I pass to it shouldn't it?  I'm not making a call to `ClearAllPools()`.